# Polymer How to style #scroller selectively

Tags: css, polymer

I have the following situation. I have created a dialog element as illustrated by this fragment:

```
<polymer-element name="my-dialog">
    <template>
        <paper-action-dialog id='myDialog'>
            ... my content ...
        <paper-button raised dismissive>Done</paper-button>
      </paper-action-dialog>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

In my main page I include the element (I have not shown the triggering event)

```
<my-dialog class='pickMe'>
</my-dialog>
```

I now want to style the #scroller in core-overlay which is used in turn by paper-action-dialog. The following will work but will style all core-overlays:

```
html /deep/ #dialog::shadow #scroller {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

I want to be more specific as I may have other dialogs included on the page. I'd like to do something like:

```
.pickMe /deep/ #dialog::shadow #scroller {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

But this won't work as my-dialog is not an ancestor in the shadow dom. (The highest ancestor is core-overlay-layer)

I can use the id on paper-action-dialog (which is in the shadow dom tree) to be more specific:

```
html /deep/ #myDialog /deep/ #scroller {...}
```

However this will select all occurrences of my-dialog

So my question is how to selectively style the #scroller so I just pick up the one in my-dialog with the pickMe class?

Comment: Have you tried `html /deep/ .pickMe /deep/ #dialog::shadow #scroller` ?

Comment: @mohammad Yes I did try that but it faces the same issue as my-dialog  is not in the shadow dom tree. I have to look at how core-overlay is implemented to see why this is. paper-dialog is an extension of core-overlay and it may be that I have to implement my-dialog as an extension to paper-dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

here is the situation. As currently implemented paper-action-dialog is an extension of paper-dialog base which in turn extends core-overlay. If you wrap paper-action-dialog in your own custom element the way core overlay builds the shadow down your tag will never appear in the shadow dom and it cannot be used to specifically style the enclosed paper-action-dialog.

I came up with two solutions. The first is to stay with strategy of enclosing paper-action-dialog but pass something that can then be used to style paper-action-dialog. The following works:

```
<polymer-element name="my-dialog" attributes='myHandle>
    <template>
        <paper-action-dialog id='myDialog' class="{{myHandle}}">
            ... my content ...
        <paper-button raised dismissive>Done</paper-button>
      </paper-action-dialog>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

If you use the element thus:

```
<my-dialog myHandle='pickMe'>
</my-dialog>
```

Then you can selectively style the instance of my-dialog with:

```
html /deep/ .pickMe /deep/ #scroller {}
```

as paper-action-dialog will be in the shadow dom with the class pickMe.

The second approach is to implement my-dialog as an extension to paper-dialog-base. You can just modify paper-action-dialog, save it as my-dialog and include whatever content and styling you like. my-dialog will then be in the shadow dom and you can style it easily with something like

```
my-dialog.pickMe /deep/ #scroller {}
```

paper-action-dialog is a pretty simple extension to paper-dialog-base so should be easy to maintain.

I prefer the second approach.